# XPath, test last attribute value from list

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, saxon

I'm trying to test the last attribute value from this input XML. I'm using Saxon and XSLT 2.0

```
<history>
  <value date='2010-01-01' price='5.99'/>
  <value date='2010-01-02' price='6.49'/>
  <value date='2010-01-03' price='6.19'/>
</history>
```

I've tried these with the Eclipse Xpath evaluator, it gets the last node, but the attribute comparison does not evaluate to true.

```
 (/history/value[@price])[last()] = '6.19'
 (/history/value[last()])[@price] = '6.19'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is this:

```
/history/value[last()]/@price = '6.19'
```